# Enabling gulp-watch conditionally with gulp-if (or something else)

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-less

Basically I want to setup my task so that if I do `gulp less --watch` it will watch, otherwise just do the build. This is what I have so far:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var cli = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./client/styles/styles.less', './client/styles/libs.less'])
    .pipe(less({ sourceMap: !cli.production }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/styles'))
    .pipe(gulpif(cli.watch, watch()));
});
```

What happens is that it still executes the `watch`, but doesn't pass any files. This also prevents the task from `process.exit()`ing..

I'm assuming I have to either wrap it in something, or use an alternate method (not `gulp-if`)..

Comment: So you want that if `--watch` is passed you want to build + continue watching and build again if LESS sources change?

Comment: Would love to get @robrich's input here :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gulp-watch` is an endless stream, so *if called* it will never allow the process to exit. Your task always call `watch()` in order to pass it to `gulpif` even when the if won't need it. This means you will be running an unattached watcher. Additionally, the watcher needs to be first in your pipe chain so it can re-trigger the remaining handlers.

What you need to do is use the command line argument to conditionally call and attach `watch()`. run a task that does the watching. Also, use `gulp-plumber` (https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-plumber) to keep the stream working if you have an error after the watcher.

```
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
gulp.task('less', function () {
    var src = gulp.src(['./client/styles/styles.less', './client/styles/libs.less']);

    if (cli.watch) {  // watch() won't be called without the command line arg
        src = src.pipe(watch()).plumber(); 
    }

    return src.pipe(less({ sourceMap: !cli.production }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/styles'));
});
```

Comment: I found a work around, not exactly like yours but it works as well. I'm using `pipe(cli.watch ? watch() : gutil.noop())`. Thanks for this solution.

Comment: `lazypipe().pipe(watch)` would probably also work https://www.npmjs.org/package/lazypipe

Answer (score 0):

Not so elegant, but this works based on `NODE_ENV` (pulled in with [gulp-environments](https://github.com/gunpowderlabs/gulp-environments)) which I wanted to determine start of `watch` by (yes in development, no in production/deployment). Disclaimer: I just started using Gulp (4.0 beta so that `gulp.series` works), so this might be terrible, but it gets the job done.. :-)

```
var environments = require('gulp-environments');
var development = environments.development;
var production = environments.production;

if (development()) {
    gulp.task('default', gulp.series('flow', 'babel', 'cleanup', 'watch'), function(done) {
        done();
    });
}
else {
    gulp.task('default', gulp.series('flow', 'babel', 'compress', 'cleanup'), function(done) {
        done();
    });
}
```